# SELECT only a specific set of characters (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, replace, string-function

I have a table with a specific set of characters containing the value, it's decimal and hexadecimal equivalents.

```
/-------------------------\
|value|decimal|hexadecimal|
|-------------------------|
|    a|     97|       0061|
|    b|     98|       0062|
|    c|     99|       0063|
|    d|    100|       0064|
|-------------------------|
```

How can I select a column ignoring any character that is not in this table?

Edit 1: Let's say this table is called "tb_abcd" and a wanna select the column "user_name" from the table "tb_users".

Table content:

```
/---------\
|user_name|
|---------|
| Samuel  |
| Paul    |
| Chris   |
|---------|
```

Expected output (based on the character set from "tb_abcd"):

```
/---------\
|user_name|
|---------|
|    A    |
|    A    |
|    C    |
|---------|
```

I know this is a silly example, but the original table has a set of 251 characters.

Comment: Can you please **[edit]** the question and add the output you expect? Which column do you want to select? From which table?

Comment: What do you mean by "select a column ignoring any character that is not in this table"? Doesn't that just mean you'd select all values that _are_ in the table?

Comment: Where does `A`/`B`/`C` come from?

Comment: I don't understand. What if there was another row `e|    101|       0065` . What result would that give? And why does the result contain uppercase letters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as none of your 251 characters interfere with regex, this silly solution should work.

```
with keeps as (
  select string_agg(value, '') as letters
    from tb_abcd 
)
select *, 
       upper(regexp_replace(u.user_name, '[^'||k.letters||']', '', 'gi'))
  from tb_users u
 cross join keeps k;

 user_name | letters | upper 
-----------+---------+-------
 Samuel    | abcd    | A
 Paul      | abcd    | A
 Chris     | abcd    | C
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Now I transformed it into a function to use on my other reports. Here it is in case somebody need it:

declare character_set_values text := (select string_agg(value, '') as letters from tb_abcd);

 begin
     return (regexp_replace($1::text, '[^'||character_set_values||']', '', 'gi'));
 end

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you would use `regexp_replace()`:

```
select regexp_replace(t.user_name, r.regex, '', 'g')
from t cross join lateral
     (select '[^' || string_agg(value, '') || ']' as regex
      from content
     ) r
```

Note:  You need to take care if any of the characters are valid in a regular expression.  That is not the case for your sample data.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=4f2976e3b9a56d4eaed68b6f86fc87f9) is a db<>fiddle.  This returns different results from what you specify -- I can't figure out where those come from.  This does do what you describe.